# How to differentiate iOS UIKit dataSource and delegate methods for multiple objects in the same UIViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I noticed in using UITableView, UICollectionView, UIPickerView, UIScrollView, ..., and numerous other UIKit classes that the UIViewController containing the object instance often bears the role of DataSource and Delegate.

I understand from Apple's documentation what these data source and delegate methods are called, and how to implement them... for a single instance of each class.

My question is, how do you handle different instances in the same UIViewController?  For example, if I have two UICollectionViews, or three UIPickerViews, ...., or fifty UIScrollViews?  I can implement the data source method only once per UIViewController, but I somehow have to tell the program different instructions?

The only thing I can conceive is a gigantic switch statement or a bunch of cascading if-else if-else comparing the input to the delegate or data source method to each object instance in the UIViewController, which might get out of hand if there are many.

Comment: @Christian: Off-topic. Yes as I mentioned in the original post, I know the first argument is the caller, but that results in long cascading if comparisons or switch statements, generally not a good solution to programming problems. Is there a smarter way?

Comment: @Kampai: Not impossible. Different UICollections to show different collections, obviously.  For example, the photo collections of two users. If everyone just needed only one UICollectionView, why do you think Apple made it separate from UICollectionViewController? Stop being so presumptuous and stay on-topic.

Comment: @Simon McLoughlin: I don't need two VC classes.  I have one VC, just multiple items of the same class that call the same delegate method.

Comment: @Cindeselia sorry I misunderstood your issue. As mentioned by others, each delegate fires with a reference to the element that created it. You can use this to compare

Comment: @Cindeselia I don't see, why my comment is off-topic. Nevertheless, you can extract your delegate code to an external class and assign each UIView another delegate. This way you keep your VC's code clean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While we're used to using our view controller as the delegate, there's no need to do so. You can actually create `NSObject` subclasses that conform to the delegate protocol in question. You can then instantiate those objects and use them as the delegates of the UI objects (or whatever) as needed.

For example, consider a scene where I have two text fields, one which permits only numeric values, and one that does not accept numeric values. I can write a separate delegate object for each type of text field.

1. If implementing this programmatically, I would manually instantiate the two delegate objects, keep some strong references to them in my view controller, and then in `viewDidLoad` I can set each text field's delegate to be the appropriate delegate object.
2. If doing this in Interface Builder, you can actually drag an "Object" from the "Object Library" onto the scene (either in the bar above the scene or the document outline to the left of the scene):

   [image]

   You can then specify the class for this object:

   [image]

   Repeat this for all of your delegate objects:

   [image]

   And finally, you can go to your text field and specify the delegate by control dragging to the delegate object you added to the scene:

   [image]

   Doing it in Interface Builder means that it completely takes care of the instantiation of this delegate object for me and I have to do nothing in view controller's code.

Bottom line, if you want distinct behavior for a UI object, you can just instantiate a separate delegate object that manifests the desired behavior, and use that as the UI object's delegate. This pattern of instantiating separate delegate objects is common in iOS 7 custom transitions (where we have all sorts of delegate objects banging about), but can be used in this context, too.

BTW, you can obviously just subclass the UI control in question, too, and further encapsulate the logic there. That works equally well.

Answer (score 1):

By creating referencing outlet for each controller,for example if you have two UITableView ,You can create outlet for each such as table1 and table2. To set number of rows in a section for these table ,you can code like follow

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if (tableView == table1) {
        return 10;
    }

    if (tableView == table2) {
        return 5;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I mentioned that possibility in my original post.  What's a better way?  Exhaustively listing 50 or however many comparisons just doesn't seem like a good scalable solution...

Answer (score 0):

You can create independent UIViews for each tableView or collection view with it's own .swift and .xib (and maybe if they are very similar you can reuse them). Doing that you will have the tableView and collecionView delegate methods in separated files and everything will be more clear. In your view controller you will just have to place the views, but you won't have any delegate methods there.

Answer (score 0):

Well you are asking to differentiate the views with datasource & delegate in a smarter way. But you are overthinking this thing.

1. Everyone takes the different tableviews or pickers because they wan't be the same.
   Otherwise they can be reused.
2. Now if they are going to be different from others then ultimately somewhere in your code you have to put the if...else or case statements. For example for tableview while setting the value of an UILabel or any value in your UITableViewCell.
3. If you are facing a such an issue that you have to put that many scrollviews or something in only one `UIViewController` then its an impossible situation if you are following the coding standards or may be your app design is faulty.